# How to select an Image within a Button components in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

From code behind I need to get and set a property for `RightArrowImage`. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
    <Button x:Name="RightArrowBtn">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="RightArrowImage"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Source="Assets/common/right_grey.png"
                    />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`FrameworkTemplate.FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var img = RightArrowBtn.Template.FindName("RightArrowImage", RightArrowBtn) as Image
```

but your `Button` needs to be fully loaded in order to do so

Comment: thanks, I get null, probably Button is not fully loaded. Could you suggest me how to solve it?

Comment: did you try calling it in `Window.Loaded` event for example?

Comment: I had to use this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded); in public MainWindow(){} works thanks